# What is needed to refactor this Twisted code for Python3.6?

Tags: python, twisted

Having trouble figuring out how to refactor some code written for Twisted under Python2.7 for Python3.6

I have been trying to figure out how to get the repository at https://github.com/stylesuxx/udp-hole-punching to work on Python3.6, using the Twisted library. According to the Readme, Python2.7 is required, although Twisted should work on Python3.5+. This leads me to believe that the problem is with the repository itself, although I can't figure out what to change.

I have run the code under Python2.7, and it works. The client and server will connect, and will output messages showing what connections are being made. Under Python3.5, however, no messages at all are output, and it essentially appears that nothing is happening at all. No error messages are displayed.

Comment: This isn't refactoring.  This is porting to a new Python version.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start with syntax changes, which your IDE if you use one should be highlighting, like changing `print` statements from

```
print 'text'
```

to

```
print('text')
```

See this [cheat sheet](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html) and [Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I will need to work through this, so it may take some time. I will let you know how it goes, once I have.

Comment: Ok, I ran futurize on server.py and it did make a few changes, all imports at the beginning. Nothing else seemed to have been changed. The same behavior happens when I run the program under Python3: It just says "Listening on port 9000," but does nothing else when I try to connect using client.py from another machine. It does work, however, when I run the original non-futurized version from Python2.7. In that case, it will tell me when it gets connected. So, no real progress so far. Do I need to futurize Twisted (even though it says it runs on 3.5+)? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Great that you found the issue, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have the answer. I found this page: https://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/twisted-16.6.0/core/howto/python3.html.

I found the lines in server.py which started with "self.transport.write" and sent the message as bytes, rather than strings, by using an initial b or .encode(). I also changed the line if datagram == '0' to if datagram == b'0'.

Seems to be working so far. If I hit any more obstacles I will share it here.